# Why is PrivateBinPath when creating a new AppDomain not being considered at all?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, appdomain

So when I create a new app domain, specifying PrivateBinPath doesn't seem to be working correctly. I know that it has to be a subfolder of application base.
Here's the example:

```
public class PluginHandler : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Launch()
    {
        var domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup()
        {
            ApplicationBase = Util.AssemblyDirectory,
            PrivateBinPath = @"Plugins"
        };

        appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), null, domainSetup);
        assemblyLoader = appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap
            (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(AssemblyLoader).FullName) as AssemblyLoader;

        thread = new Thread(() => 
            assemblyLoader.LoadAssembly(PluginPath, ProxyBase, this));
        thread.Start();
    }
}

public class AssemblyLoader : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private object pluginObj;
    private MethodInfo pluginStop;

    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    public bool LoadAssembly(string path, CoreBase proxyBase, PluginHandler pluginHandler)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
        var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Core))).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
        {
            FieldInfo coreBase = types[i].GetField
                ("proxyBase", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            MethodInfo pluginRun = types[i].GetMethod("PluginRun");
            pluginStop = types[i].GetMethod("PluginStop");

            if (pluginRun != null)
            {
                pluginObj = assembly.CreateInstance(types[i].FullName);
                coreBase.SetValue(pluginObj, proxyBase);
                pluginHandler.IsLoaded = true;
                pluginHandler.CorePlugin = pluginObj;

                if (!proxyBase.LaunchedPlugins.Contains(pluginHandler))
                {
                    proxyBase.LaunchedPlugins.Add(pluginHandler);
                }

                pluginRun.Invoke(pluginObj, null);

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I'm loading assembly in Proxy on new app domain, and the loaded assembly "Plugin". Now, whenever PluginRun is invoked, I get an exception FileNotFound, because it's searching for Plugin assembly in base path, yet it's in Plugins folder.

So even if specifying PrivateBinPath to PLugins folder, it doesn't seem to be able to find it.

I used Binding Log Viewer and private path is NULL, just a note.

Any solution to this issue? Thanks

Comment: One thing that's kind of suspicious to me is that you are loading the assembly directly as a byte array, from my recollection this loads the assembly without a context and so any dependencies won't be loaded by probing. You've got to use Assembly.Load with the assembly name for PrivateBinPath to be used properly.

Comment: @MikeZboray Hey Mike thanks for your response, I actually tried Load as well but how am I supposed to use Load only where it expects assemblyString and not path? LoadFile first, then get Asm string and use Load again? Thanks

Comment: You mean you don't know the assembly name because its a plugin and you are in the process of discovering them? :) You can get the name from the aptly named AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName method. That doesn't load the assembly (as far as reflection is concerned). It just reads the file metadata. Hopefully that works!

Comment: @MikeZboray Thanks Mike! I tried exactly that as well, even again now but no luck, the privateBinPath is still not considered and I'm getting FileNotFound exception :(

Comment: I’ve always used an assembly resolver inside the new AppDomain

Comment: @MickyD Hey, I even tried assembly resolver, but subscribing when creating the appDomain, it never gets hits, any idea why?

Comment: The assembly resolver needs to be created and subscribed inside the child AppDomain, by `AssemblyLoader` in other words.  Do it first thing